# Bug with image picker : When tapping on the album button the camera opens up

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two different buttons : Camera button and Album button. When tapping on the album button in order to select an image from photo library, the camera opens. Once I opened the camera by tapping in the camera button, the album works correctly.

I don't know what to do. Here is my code :

```
struct MemeCreator: View {
    @State private var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .camera
    @State private var image: Image?
    @State private var showingImagePicker = false
    @State private var inputImage: UIImage?
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Group {
                if let image = image {
                    Rectangle()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .overlay(
                            image
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                        )
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    Button(
                        action: {
                            sourceType = .camera
                            showingImagePicker = true
                        }
                    ) {
                        Image(systemName: "camera.fill")
                    }
                    
                    Button(
                        action: {
                            sourceType = .photoLibrary
                            showingImagePicker = true
                        }
                    ) {
                        Text("Album")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingImagePicker, onDismiss: loadImage) {
            ImagePicker(image: $inputImage, sourceType: sourceType)
        }
    }
```

Here is the image picker's code :
[Image picker's script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyEmM.png)

Comment: Can u share the code of your `ImagePicker` view

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  you could try this:

```
class SourceType: ObservableObject {
    @Published var pickerType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .camera
}

struct MemeCreator: View {
    @StateObject var source = SourceType()  // <--- here
    
    @State private var image: Image?
    @State private var showingImagePicker = false
    @State private var inputImage: UIImage?
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Group {
                if let image = image {
                    Rectangle()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .overlay(
                            image
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                        )
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("title"), displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                Button(
                    action: {
                        source.pickerType = .camera  // <--- here
                        showingImagePicker = true
                    }
                ) {
                    Image(systemName: "camera.fill")
                }
                
                Button(
                    action: {
                        source.pickerType = .photoLibrary  // <--- here
                        showingImagePicker = true
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Album")
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingImagePicker, onDismiss: loadImage) {
            ImagePicker(image: $inputImage, sourceType: source.pickerType) // <--- here
        }
        
    }
    
    func loadImage() {
        print("-----> loadImage")
    }
    
}
```

EDIT2:

Alternatively, you can also do this in your code, using the sheet(items:...) and making the required Identifiable:

```
extension UIImagePickerController.SourceType: Identifiable {
    public var id: Self { self }
}

struct MemeCreator: View {
    @State private var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType? = nil
    ....
    
        .sheet(item: $sourceType, onDismiss: loadImage) { source in
            ImagePicker(image: $inputImage, sourceType: source)
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with new code. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem which is to create two sheet view modifier on those two buttons. Here is what it looks like :

```
ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(
                        action: {
                            sourceType = .camera
                            showingCamera = true
                        }
                    ) {
                        Image(systemName: "camera.fill")
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showingCamera, onDismiss: loadImage) {
                        ImagePicker(image: $inputImage, sourceType: .camera)
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    Button(
                        action: {
                            sourceType = .photoLibrary
                            showingImagePicker = true
                        }
                    ) {
                        Text("Album")
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showingImagePicker, onDismiss: loadImage) {
                        ImagePicker(image: $inputImage, sourceType: .photoLibrary)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
```